# I need import ActivityInfo in file using C++ UE4

Tags: android, c++, unreal-engine4

i need to add function for portrait and landscape and works only landscape, portrait not works because I need ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, This is not possible because library ActivityInfo doesn't exist.

```
 JNIEnv* JE = FAndroidApplication::GetJavaEnv();
    jmethodID SetOrientationID = FJavaWrapper::FindMethod(JE, FJavaWrapper::GameActivityClassID, "setRequestedOrientation", "(I)V", false);
    FJavaWrapper::CallVoidMethod(JE, FJavaWrapper::GameActivityThis, SetOrientationID, 0);
    // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

I need import ActivityInfo but I can't find file for that in C++ UE4

Comment: That value is a regular static variable in the ActivityInfo class, or you can look up the value in the documentation and pass that directly.

Comment: yes I know that but where is this file? I can' found this file inside my project or UE4?

Comment: It is [part of the Android sdk](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)